# How to get the current page URL in the view?

Tags: playframework

I want to use URL of current page in all my pages on my site for creating link button.

I can do the following in my controller:

```
Http.Request.current().getBase() + Http.Request.current().url;
```

But how can I do this in view? Is there direct way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You  can access the `Http.Request.current()` in the view, as simply `request`.

So, you need

```
${request.getBase()}${request.url}
```