# Play Framework 2.0 Find the current action in a view

Tags: css, playframework, playframework-2.0

In a Play Framework 2.0 app, I would like to be able to specify a CSS class for the active page.  How do I that?

```
<li @if( ) { class="active" }> 
  <a href="@routes.Application.index()"> Home </a> 
</li>
```

Specifically, what do I put in the if statement?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8922364/681807

Comment: @MyHeadHurts thanks, that is a good link.  Not exactly what I was looking for here, but I will need that info a bit later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@request.uri works at least with play framework 2 to see more read http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.Request.html

Edit: You can try this for example..

```
@if(request.uri.contains("home")){ 
  ..home word in url..
} else {
  ..home word not in url..
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing 'request.uri.equals(routes.Application.index().toString()' instead of hardcoding "home".  Anyhow, thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction.